Как лучше передать обученную модель ML из одного процесса в другой
Есть два процесса. Один процесс - обучает модель ML. Второй процесс должен использовать обученную модель для предсказаний. Я представлял себе передачу модели так: в первом процессе модель обучается, далее с помощью встроенного метода или, в случае если такой метод не предусмотрен в модели, с помощью pickle, модель сохраняется в файл, а второй процесс этот файл открывает и использует. Но вот в этом вопросе коллеги мне сказали, что передача данных между процессами с помощью файлов - так себе идея и надо использовать либо БД либо брокеры сообщений (Kafka, RabbitMQ и т.д.).
Два вопроса:
А можно ли (удобно ли) использовать брокеры именно в этом случае?
Какой способ передачи данных такого типа вы считаете лучшим в этом случае и почему?

Передача модели через файловую систему - отличная идея. Базы данных и брокеры добавите когда будете масштабировать решение на десятки и сотни серверов. А пока чем проще, тем лучше.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Благодарю! Так и буду действовать.
